# LINQ and Entity Framework - Avoiding subqueries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm having really hard time tuning up one of my `Entity Framework` generated queries in my application. It is very basic query but for some reason `EF` uses multiple inner subqueries which seem to perform horribly in `DB` instead of using joins.

Here's my LINQ code:

```
Projects.Select(proj => new ProjectViewModel()
                {
                    Name = proj.Name,
                    Id = proj.Id,
                    Total = proj.Subvalue.Where(subv =>
                        subv.Created >= startDate
                        && subv.Created <= endDate
                        &&
                        (subv.StatusId == 1 ||
                         subv.StatusId == 2))
                        .Select(c => c.SubValueSum)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                        .Sum()
                })
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Total)
                .Take(10);
```

EF generates really complex query with multiple subqueries which has awful query performance like this:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project3].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project3].[C1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        (SELECT 
            SUM([Join1].[A1]) AS [A1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                CASE WHEN ([Project1].[C1] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as decimal(18)) ELSE [Project1].[SubValueSum] END AS [A1]
                FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
                    [Extent2].[SubValueSum] AS [SubValueSum], 
                    cast(1 as tinyint) AS [C1]
                    FROM [dbo].[Subvalue] AS [Extent2]
                    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]) AND ([Extent2].[Created] >= '2015-08-01') AND ([Extent2].[Created] <= '2015-10-01') AND ([Extent2].[StatusId] IN (1,2)) ) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1
            )  AS [Join1]) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Project] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ProjectCountryId] = 77) AND ([Extent1].[Active] = 1)
    )  AS [Project2]
)  AS [Project3]
ORDER BY [Project3].[C1] DESC;
```

The execution time of the query generated by EF is `~10 seconds`. But when I write the query by hand like this:

```
select 
    TOP (10)
    Proj.Id,
    Proj.Name,
    SUM(Subv.SubValueSum) AS Total
from 
    SubValue as Subv
left join
    Project as Proj on Proj.Id = Subv.ProjectId
where
    Subv.Created > '2015-08-01' AND Subv.Created <= '2015-10-01' AND Subv.StatusId IN (1,2)
group by
    Proj.Id,
    Proj.Name
order by 
    Total DESC
```

The execution time is near instant; below `30ms`.

The problem clearly lies in my ability to write good `EF` queries with LINQ but no matter what I try to do (using `Linqpad` for testing) I just can't write similar performant query with `LINQ\EF` as I can write by hand. I've trie querying the *SubValue* table and *Project* table but the endcome is mostly the same: multiple ineffective nested subqueries instead of a single join doing the work.

How can I write a query which imitates the hand written `SQL` shown above? How can I control the actual query generated by `EF`? And most importantly: how can I get `Linq2SQL` and `Entity Framework` to use `Joins` when I want to instead of nested subqueries.

Comment: With **LINQ** you're probalby using a `DataContext`. Have a look at the `DataContext.LoadOptions` property [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.loadoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..

Comment: set context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false, you will get a huge improvement.

Comment: @JanUnld thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure how it would help in this specific problem? Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @Nikita the problem is not tracking. The problem is that EF generates very ineffective query and I would like to know how can I get better control for the actual SQL generated by EF/ling2sql. So how can I make it to use joins instead of ineffective sub queries?

Comment: Entity Framework and LINQ To SQL are not the same. The generated SQL looks like it was generated by Entity Framework. If this is correct I suggest that you remove the [linq-to-sql] tag and add the [entity-framework] tag.

Comment: @MartinLiversage indeed, thanks. Fixed the text and changed the tags. Thanks!

Comment: Try writing the Linq query like the SQL query with Joins and group bys

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, LINQPad uses LINQ To SQL when you create a connection. However, you can create a connection in LINQPad from an assembly with an EF Context. The SQL output option will display the actual SQL for queries that use either LINQ To SQL or EF connections.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I created EntityLite. Real life queries are complex and EF generated queries perform poorly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF generates SQL from the LINQ expression you provide and you cannot expect this conversion to completely unravel the structure of whatever you put into the expression in order to optimize it. In your case you have created an expression tree that for each project will use a navigation property to sum some subvalues related to the project. This results in nested subqueries as you have discovered.

To improve on the generated SQL you need to avoid navigating from project to subvalue before doing all the operations on subvalue and you can do this by creating a join (which is also what you do in you hand crafted SQL):

```
var query = from proj in context.Project
            join s in context.SubValue.Where(s => s.Created >= startDate && s.Created <= endDate && (s.StatusId == 1 || s.StatusId == 2)) on proj.Id equals s.ProjectId into s2
            from subv in s2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { proj, subv } into x
            group x by new { x.proj.Id, x.proj.Name } into g
            select new {
              g.Key.Id,
              g.Key.Name,
              Total = g.Select(y => y.subv.SubValueSum).Sum()
            } into y
            orderby y.Total descending
            select y;
var result = query.Take(10);
```

The basic idea is to join projects on subvalues restricted by a `where` clause. To perform a left join you need the `DefaultIfEmpty()` but you already know that.

The joined values (`x`) are then grouped and the summation of `SubValueSum` is performed in each group.

Finally, ordering and `TOP(10)` is applied.

The generated SQL still contains subqueries but I would expect it to more efficient compared to SQL generated by your query:

```
SELECT TOP (10)
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1],
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Id],
        [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [Name]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [K1],
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [K2],
            SUM([Extent2].[SubValueSum]) AS [A1]
            FROM  [dbo].[Project] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SubValue] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Created] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[Created] <= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent2].[StatusId] IN (1,2)) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ProjectId])
            GROUP BY [Extent1].[Id], [Extent1].[Name]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] DESC
```

Comment: Well this was a really nice answer and explained quite a few things about how EF actually generates the SQL. Thank you very much! The resulting SQL indeed runs much faster :)

Comment: As a note, LINQ to SQL generates much more efficient SQL than EF.